# Como exibir mensagens múltiplas de dados existentes no servidor PHP

Tags: php, mysql, if, while

Olá,
Neste código gostaria de exibir duas mensagem de dados existentes no servidor sendo  a matricula (que já funciona perfeitamente) e o e-mail. Já tentei algumas formas de inserir essas duas mensagens, porém, sem exito... segue o código:

```
<?php

include_once 'conexao.php';
$session_start = session_start();

$nome       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputNome', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
$email      = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputEmail', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$telefone   = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputTel', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$matricula  = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'inputMatricula', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$querySelect = $link->query("select * from tb_clientes");
$array_emails = [];
$array_matriculas = [];

while ($matriculas = $querySelect->fetch_assoc()):
    $matricula_existentes = $matriculas['matricula'];
    array_push($array_matriculas, $matricula_existentes);

endwhile;
if (in_array($matricula,$array_matriculas)):
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center red-text'>" . 'Já existe um servidor cadastrado com essa matrícula' . "</p>";
    header("Location:../");
else: 
    $queryInsert = $link->query("insert into tb_clientes values(default,'$nome','$email','$telefone','$matricula')");
    $affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows ($link);

  if ($affected_rows > 0):


    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p class='center green-text'>".'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'."<br>";
    header("Location:../");   
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: Qual o erro que você recebe?

Comment: não entendi bem, vc quer uma msg de retorno caso o email já exista?

Comment: Exatamente Wees

Comment: gustavox, nao tem erro no codigo, eu so quero uma segunda mensagem de retorno caso o e-mail exista